# Как сделать ограничение выбора даты?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, bootstrap, jquery-ui

Есть календарь [тут](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers)

В этом примере два календаря, второй ограничивает выбор не меньше даты первого...

**Вопрос:** как сделать в первом календаре ограничение выбора min значение = (текущий день+1day), а во 
втором - ограничение min значение = ( результат первого календаря + 1day) ?

*Если сегодня 08.09, то выбрать можно от 09.09, если в первом выбрано 09.09, то во втором доступны даты от 10.09*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/vdLLw959/2/)

```
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment().add(1, 'days')
  }).on('dp.change', function (selected) {
    $("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker('minDate',selected.date.add(1, 'days'));
    $(this).datetimepicker('hide');
 });

  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
     minDate: moment().add(2, 'days')
 }).on('dp.change', function (selected) {
    $(this).datetimepicker('hide');
 });;
});
```

Мин.дата устанавливается через параметр minDate. Для начала устанавливаем их с разницей 1 день между первым и вторым календарём. А потом при изменении первого календаря - будет меняться мин.дата второго календаря.